# How to log only StreamHandler logs?

Tags: python, logging

I only want logs produced by StreamHandler, but for some reason everything is getting logged twice. Formatting root logger doesn't seem to work either.

I have searched through the logging documentation and tried to figure out what the problem is but I can't seem to find anything related to my issue. I've also tried a few different setups but can't find anything that works.

Here's the latest thing I've tried:

```py
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

logger.info('Modeling for date %s, saving outputs %s', date_string, save_loc_str)
```

Output:

```
2019-10-17 14:20:47,547 - __main__ - INFO - Modeling for date 2019-10-17, saving outputs to S3
INFO:__main__:Modeling for date 2019-10-17, saving outputs to S3
```

I've also tried to simply change the format in basicConfig but the format doesn't get updated:

```py
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logger.info('Modeling for date %s, saving outputs %s', date_string, save_loc_str)
```

Output:

```
INFO:__main__:Modeling for date 2019-10-17, saving outputs to S3
```

Simply

```py
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

logging.info('Modeling for date %s, saving outputs %s', date_string, save_loc_str)
```

Won't work either, and gives the same output as the previous :/

Comment: Your last example works correctly for me. For just using StreamHandler, you can use `logging.basicConfig` as you did. What OS and Python version do you use?

Comment: OS X Catalina, Python 3.7.4. Could it be that my logging package is just tripping and I need to reinstall it? I really don't see any other fix for this.

Comment: I had something similar on Windows, bit couldn't find the cause before it disapoeared by itself. I doubt reinstalling Python would do anything. Do you have any package installed? Do you run your script with Python directly or via another tool (like `manage.py` for Django)?

Comment: 1. Multiple, inside a virtualenv if i understand you correctly. 2. Directly

Comment: Can you try in a freshly created virtualenv?